# error: conflicting declaration. compiling c code with g++

Tags: c++, g++, googletest

I have a lib which I want to test using google test framework. The code is very old and I can't change anything in actual code.

I have included a header file `first.h` which have following `typedef`:

```
typedef struct aList* aList;
```

and in another file, say `second.c`, `struct` is defined as:

```
struct aList {
    aRecord* top;
};
```

and in my `TestFile.cc`:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "First.h"

TEST(First_Test, Create)
{
    FuncName();
}
```

when I compile it using:

```
g++ -isystem ../../../test/framework/gtest/googletest/include -isystem ../../../test/framework/gtest/googlemock/include -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread --coverage -Iinclude/path -c TestFile.cc -Lpath/to/lib -llibfile
```

I get following error:

> ```
> error: conflicting declaration typedef struct aList* aList
> error: struct aList has a previous declaration as struct aList
> ```

There are no include guards in header files. But I don't think issue is because of that.

Any clue how to fix this?

**EDIT**

Here is a complete verifiable example.

Contents of FirstFile.h:

```
#include "SecondFile.h"

typedef struct aList* aList;

void func();
```

Contents of FirstFile.c:

```
#include "FirstFile.h"

void func()
{

}

void main()
{
    func();
}
```

Contents of SecondFile.h:

```
struct aList {
    int* top;
};
```

Contents of TestCode.cc:

```
#include "FirstFile.h"

void funcTest()
{
    func();
}
```

Command to compile:

```
g++ TestCode.cc -o TestCode
```

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] that reproduces the error please.

Comment: Any clue? Not using one name `aList` for struct and typedef of pointer to struct?

Comment: I know struct name and typedef name are same. what i want to know is if there is way to test this code using google test framework without changing the actual code

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ please check the edit

Comment: @ArslanKhan Use different name for `struct aList` and a variable created for it. Ther eror message is pretty clear. Also the c and gcc tag are completely irrelevant here.

Comment: Problem is i can't change the actual code.

Comment: gcc FirstFile.c -o FirstFile compiles fine but g++ FirstFile.c -o FirstFile
gives same error.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately some little devil in your company has managed to get non-conforming c++ code into your libraries.

Simply trying to compile this:

```
struct aList {};
typedef struct aList* aList;
```

results in:

```
2 : error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct aList* aList'
typedef struct aList* aList;
^
1 : note: previous declaration as 'struct aList'
struct aList {};
```

I am afraid you are compelled to fix the faulty library.